# How to count consecutive consonants at beginning of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm still coming to terms with Regex and want to formulate an expression that will let me count the number of successive consonants at the beginning of a string. E.g. `'Cherry'` will return `2`, `'hello'` `1`, `'schlepp'` `4` and so on. Since the number isn't predetermined (although English probably has some upper limit on initial consonants!) I'd need some flexible expression, but I'm a bit stuck about how to write it. Any pointers would be welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
'Cherry'[/\A[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*/i].length #=> 2
```

The regex matches zero or more consonants at the beginning of the string. [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns the matching part and [`length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-length) determines its length.

You can also express the consonants character class more succinct by intersecting `[a-z]` and `[^aeiou]` via `&&`:

```
'Cherry'[/\A[a-z&&[^aeiou]]*/i].length #=> 2
```

Comment: `"1. Cherry cobler."[r].length #=> 0`, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line would work:

```
>> 'Cherry'.downcase.split(/([aeiou].*)/).first.length
# => 2
>> 'hello'.downcase.split(/([aeiou].*)/).first.length
# => 1
>> 'schlepp'.downcase.split(/([aeiou].*)/).first.length
# => 4
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. Why do you use the first method here, before .length?

Comment: `split` will return an array of 2 strings. We need the `length` of only first string. Accept and upvote if the answer helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: What if the string begins with something other than a letter?

Comment: user211309, answers are to be accepted if they are helpful *and* are the most helpful of all answers submitted. Also, there's no rush in selecting an answer. Many here wait a couple of hours at least. Sajin, it is unprofessional, imo, to request that one's answer be selected, especially when the asker is new to SO and possibly not familiar with the criteria for applying the checkmark. I for one would *never* award the greenie to someone who asked for it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I completely agree with "answers are to be accepted if they are helpful and are the most helpful of all answers submitted". I thought this was the answer he was looking for when he said thanks. So i thought it was better to have an answer accepted if it is correct rather than leaving it unaccepted, so that people like us will be encouraged to answer more questions. I also accept the fact that Stefan's answer is a much better one. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to replace from the first vowel until end of string by nothing then take the length:

```
'Cherry'.gsub(/[aeiou].*$/,"").length
```

Comment: What if the string does not begin with a letter? For example, `"1. Make dinner reservarions".

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Sure, it will not work (as other answers) but those cases haven't been explicitly requested by OP.

Comment: The OP only said the object was a string, so why not write the method so  that it works regardless of whether it begins with a letter?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use a regular expression.

```
CONSONANTS = (('a'..'z').to_a - 'aeiou'.chars).join
  #=> "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def consecutive_constants(str)
  e, a = str.each_char.chunk { |c| CONSONANTS.include?(c.downcase) }.first
  e ? a.size : 0
end

consecutive_constants("THIS is nuts")       #=> 2
consecutive_constants("Is this ever cool?") #=> 0
consecutive_constants("1. this is wrong")   #=> 0
```

Note

```
enum = "THIS is nuts".each_char.chunk { |c| CONSONANTS.include?(c.downcase) }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000000010e1a40>:each>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by applying [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) (or [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a)):

```
enum.entries
  #=> [[true, ["T", "H"]], [false, ["I"]], [true, ["S"]], [false, [" ", "i"]],
  #    [true, ["s"]], [false, [" "]], [true, ["n"]], [false, ["u"]], [true, ["t", "s"]]]
```

Continuing,

```
  e, a = enum.first
    #=> [true, ["T", "H"]]
  e #=> true
  a #=> ["T", "H"]
  a.size
    #=> 2
```